# PlayOnLinux via Steam fails badly! (3 of 3 failed)

Tags: games, steam, playonlinux, crash, error-handling

Okay the following games did not work via steam but Steam worked...

*DayZ (black box in corner then goes away!)

*R.U.S.E. (stuck on loading screen!)

*Unreal Tournament 3: Black Edition (logo apears and it minimize and wont come back up!)

Anyone knows what causes this or isnt POL meant to be used this way?

Or is it the games that arent supportd by it maybe?

HELP! D=

BTW: World of tanks works fine, even better than it did on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to disable the Steam Overlay?

Many people have this issue where the first key pressed on the keyboard when the steam overlay is enabled makes the game crash

Comment: I managed to get UT3 working and RUSE to work barely but RUSE only works if its run in a virtual desktop... Il try that ASAP! ;D